# How to adjust path links in TreeView D3.js

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, path

```js
var root;
 var boxWidth = 160,
     boxHeight = 40,
     duration = 750; // duration of transitions in ms
     
     var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
     .projection(function (d) {
     return [d.y+70, d.x];
 });

 // Setup zoom and pan
/*  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
   .scaleExtent([.1,1])
   .on('zoom', function(){
     svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
   })
   // Offset so that first pan and zoom does not jump back to the origin
   .translate([150, 200]); */

 var svg = d3.select("#infovis").append("svg")
   .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMinYMin meet")
   .attr('viewBox', "0 0 800 650")
   /* .call(zoom) */
   .append('g')
   
   // Left padding of tree so that the whole root node is on the screen.
   // TODO: find a better way
   .attr("transform", "translate(100,250)");

 var tree = d3.layout.tree()
   
   // Using nodeSize we are able to control
   // the separation between nodes. If we used
   // the size parameter instead then d3 would
   // calculate the separation dynamically to fill
   // the available space.
   .nodeSize([100, 200])
   
   // By default, cousins are drawn further apart than siblings.
   // By returning the same value in all cases, we draw cousins
   // the same distance apart as siblings.
   .separation(function(){
     return .5;
   })
   
   // Tell d3 what the child nodes are. Remember, we're drawing
   // a tree so the ancestors are child nodes.
   .children(function(person){
     
     // If the person is collapsed then tell d3
     // that they don't have any ancestors.
     if(person.collapsed){
       return;
     } else {
       return person._parents;
     }
   });
   var json = //not ablepasete data 
   var jsonFromController = $("#treeViewJsonStr").val();
   if(jsonFromController) {
    try{
      if(jsonFromController!="No results found") {
 
        json = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonFromController );
        json._parents.forEach(function(gen2){
            collapse(gen2);
        });
        root = json;
        root.x0 = 0;
        root.y0 = 0;
        draw(root);
      } else {
       $("#infovis").html("<br/><br/>"+jsonFromController);
      }
     }catch(e){
     console.log(e);
     }
   }
   
   
   function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    if (d.parent) {
      d.parent.children.forEach(function(element) {
        if (d !== element) {
          collapse(element);
        }
      });
    }
 //   update(d);
  }
   
  


 function draw(source){
   
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
     links = tree.links(nodes);
  
   nodes.forEach(function (d) {
       d.y = d.depth *250;
   });
   // Update the linksâ¦
   var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
       .data(links, function (d) {
       return d.target.id;
   });

   // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
   link.enter().insert("path", "g")
       .attr("class", "link")
       .attr("x", boxWidth )
       .attr("y", boxHeight)
       .attr("d", function (d) {
       var o = {
           x: source.x0,
           y: source.y0
       };
       return diagonal({
           source: o,
           target: o
       });
   });

   // Transition links to their new position.
   link.transition()
       .duration(duration)
       .attr("d", diagonal);

   // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
   link.exit().transition()
       .duration(duration)
       .attr("d", function (d) {
       var o = {
           x: source.x,
           y: source.y
       };
       return diagonal({
           source: o,
           target: o
       });
   })
       .remove();

   // Stash the old positions for transition.
   nodes.forEach(function (d) {
       d.x0 = d.x;
       d.y0 = d.y;
   });

   // Update nodes    
   var node = svg.selectAll("g.person")
       
       // The function we are passing provides d3 with an id
       // so that it can track when data is being added and removed.
       // This is not necessary if the tree will only be drawn once
       // as in the basic example.
       .data(nodes, function(person){ return person.id; });
       
   // Add any new nodes
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "person")
       
       // Add new nodes at the right side of their child's box.
       // They will be transitioned into their proper position.
       .attr('transform', function(person){
         return 'translate(' + source.y0  + ',' + source.x0 + ')';
       })
       .on('click', togglePerson);

   // Draw the rectangle person boxes.
   // Start new boxes with 0 size so that
   // we can transition them to their proper size.
   nodeEnter.append("rect")
       .attr({
         x: 0,
         y: 0,
         width: 0,
         height: 0
       });
   

   nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("x", -90)
 .attr("y", -15)
 .attr("width", 160)
 .attr("height", 10)
 .append("xhtml:tspan")
 
 .html(function(d) {
  if(d.type=="Invoice") {
   return "<div id='"+d.id+"' title='"+d.name+"'style='text-align:center;'>"+resizeText(d.name)+"<br/>"+d.amount+"</div>";
  } else if(d.type=="TaskOrder") {
   return "<div id='"+d.id+"' title='"+d.name+"'style='text-align:center;'>"+resizeText(d.name)+"</div>";
  }
  return "<div id='"+d.id+"' title='"+d.name+"'style='text-align:center;'>"+resizeText(d.name)+"</div>"; 
  })
   .on('click',  function(d,i){
       if (d.type =='Invoice') { //do stuff
         //dostuf
        loadInvoiceView(d.id, d.status, d.invoiceType);
       }
       });


      
   
   // Update the position of both old and new nodes
   var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
       .duration(duration) 
       .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + (d.y) + "," + d.x + ")"; });
       
   // Grow boxes to their proper size    
   nodeUpdate.select('rect')
       .attr({
         x: -(boxWidth/2),
         y: -(boxHeight/2),
         width: boxWidth,
         height: boxHeight
       })
       .style("stroke", function(d){
        if(d.type =='Invoice'){
         return "#f2ab30";
        }else if(d.type=="TaskOrder"){
         return "#489de2";
        } else {
         return "#6767ef";
        }
       })
   
   // Move text to it's proper position
   nodeUpdate.select('foreignObject')
       .attr("dx", -(boxWidth/2) + 10)
       .style('fill-opacity', 0);
   
   // Remove nodes we aren't showing anymore
   var nodeExit = node.exit()
       .transition()
       .duration(duration)
       
       // Transition exit nodes to the source's position
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
       .remove();
   
   // Shrink boxes as we remove them    
   nodeExit.select('rect')
       .attr({
         x: 0,
         y: 0,
         width: 0,
         height: 0
       });
       
   // Fade out the text as we remove it
  nodeExit.select('foreignObject')
   .style('fill-opacity', 0)
       .attr('dx', 0);
   
   // Stash the old positions for transition.
   nodes.forEach(function(person) {
     person.x0 = person.x;
     person.y0 = person.y;
   });
 }

 /**
  * Update a person's state when they are clicked.
  */
 function togglePerson(person){
    if(person.collapsed){
     person.collapsed = false;
   } else {
     collapse(person);
   }
   click(person);
   draw(person);
   
 }

 /**
  * Collapse person (hide their ancestors). We recursively
  * collapse the ancestors so that when the person is
  * expanded it will only reveal one generation. If we don't
  * recursively collapse the ancestors then when
  * the person is clicked on again to expand, all ancestors
  * that were previously showing will be shown again.
  * If you want that behavior then just remove the recursion
  * by removing the if block.
  */
 function collapse(person){
   person.collapsed = true;
   if(person._parents){
     person._parents.forEach(collapse);
   }
 }
     
 /**
  * Custom path function that creates straight connecting
  * lines. Calculate start and end position of links.
  * Instead of drawing to the center of the node,
  * draw to the border of the person profile box.
  * That way drawing order doesn't matter. In other
  * words, if we draw to the center of the node
  * then we have to draw the links first and the
  * draw the boxes on top of them.
  */
/*  function elbow(d) {
   var sourceX = d.source.x,
       sourceY = d.source.y + (boxWidth / 2),
       targetX = d.target.x,
       targetY = d.target.y - (boxWidth / 2);
       
   return "M" + sourceY + "," + sourceX
     + "H" + (sourceY + (targetY-sourceY)/2)
     + "V" + targetX 
     + "H" + targetY;
 } */

 /**
  * Use a different elbow function for enter
  * and exit nodes. This is necessary because
  * the function above assumes that the nodes
  * are stationary along the x axis.
  */
/*  function transitionElbow(d){
   return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
     + "H" + d.source.y
     + "V" + d.source.x 
     + "H" + d.source.y;
 } */

 function loadInvoiceView(invoiceId, status, invoiceType) {
//  console.log("id : "+invoiceId+" | status : "+status+" | invoiceType : "+invoiceType);
  $("#invoiceId").val(invoiceId);
  $("#invoiceType").val(invoiceType);
  $("#status").val(status);
  //submit
      <%-- submitForm('<%=VCUtils.getContextURL()%>/pub/userlogin.html'); --%>
 }
 
 function resizeText(val){
  
 if(val.length>16){
  return val.substring(0,16)+"...";
 }
 return val;
 }
 </script>
```

```css
.person rect {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.person {
  font: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="infovis"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYUm1.jpg)

unable to print json format

```
    {
    "id" : "29976",
    "name" : "20121416306",
    "type" : "Contract",
    "key" : "29976",
    "_parents" : [{
            "id" : "83979",
            "name" : "2626-41C",
            "type" : "Invoice",
            "status" : "Completed",
            "key" : "29976",
            "amount" : "205853.71000000002",
            "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
        }, {
            "id" : "86985",
            "name" : "2626-42A",
            "type" : "Invoice",
            "status" : "Completed",
            "key" : "29976",
            "amount" : "291395.12",
            "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
        }, {
            "id" : "86988",
            "name" : "2626-42C",
            "type" : "Invoice",
            "status" : "Completed",
            "key" : "29976",
            "amount" : "220331.0",
            "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
        }, {
            "id" : "90455",
            "name" : "2626-43A",
            "type" : "Invoice",
            "status" : "Completed",
            "key" : "29976",
            "amount" : "277177.64",
            "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
        }, {
            "id" : "90478",
            "name" : "2626-43L",
            "type" : "Invoice",
            "status" : "Pending",
            "key" : "29976",
            "amount" : "743964.34",
            "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
        }, {
            "id" : "20189",
            "name" : "TO13ECTPSE00012",
            "type" : "TaskOrder",
            "key" : "29976",
            "_parents" : [{
                    "id" : "38737",
                    "name" : "2626-26A",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Completed",
                    "key" : "20189",
                    "amount" : "243298.23",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id" : "21541",
            "name" : "TO13TDSBIC00122",
            "type" : "TaskOrder",
            "key" : "29976",
            "_parents" : [{
                    "id" : "86989",
                    "name" : "2626-42S",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Completed",
                    "key" : "21541",
                    "amount" : "344.78",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id" : "20906",
            "name" : "TO13ECTPSE00031",
            "type" : "TaskOrder",
            "key" : "29976",
            "_parents" : [{
                    "id" : "90477",
                    "name" : "2626-43F",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Pending",
                    "key" : "20906",
                    "amount" : "4729.41",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }, {
                    "id" : "69000",
                    "name" : "2626-36F",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Completed",
                    "key" : "20906",
                    "amount" : "7869.54",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }, {
                    "id" : "56285",
                    "name" : "2626-32F",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Completed",
                    "key" : "20906",
                    "amount" : "7423.15",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id" : "21461",
            "name" : "TO13TDSBIC00105",
            "type" : "TaskOrder",
            "key" : "29976",
            "_parents" : [{
                    "id" : "4",
                    "name" : "20140002641",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Submitted",
                    "key" : "21461",
                    "amount" : "55823035.44",
                    "invoiceType" : "VC"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id" : "22022",
            "name" : "TO13TDSBIC00228",
            "type" : "TaskOrder",
            "key" : "29976",
            "_parents" : [{
                    "id" : "86992",
                    "name" : "2626-42X",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Completed",
                    "key" : "22022",
                    "amount" : "59876.9",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }, {
                    "id" : "83988",
                    "name" : "2626-41X",
                    "type" : "Invoice",
                    "status" : "Completed",
                    "key" : "22022",
                    "amount" : "392.52",
                    "invoiceType" : "ECMS"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i am attaching here json. I tried a lot to adjust the path links to make attach to the box at front side. thanks in advance please help me in this regards how to make. and how to place the values in d attribute so the links will get adjusted

Comment: children nodes are not closing to its parent node how to close children node to its respective parent node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the path above rectangle, you will need to draw the rectangle first then the path.

So you will need to append the link creation section after the node create section:

```
   //update the nodes here
  //node code here
      // Update the linksâ¦
   var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
       .data(links, function (d) {
       return d.target.id;
   });

   // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
   link.enter().append("path", "g")
       .attr("class", "link")
       .attr("x", boxWidth )
       .attr("y", boxHeight)
       .attr("d", function (d) {
       var o = {
           x: source.x0,
           y: source.y0
       };
       return diagonal({
           source: o,
           target: o
       });
   });

   // Transition links to their new position.
   link.transition()
       .duration(duration)
       .attr("d", diagonal);

   // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
   link.exit().transition()
       .duration(duration)
       .attr("d", function (d) {
       var o = {
           x: source.x,
           y: source.y
       };
       return diagonal({
           source: o,
           target: o
       });
   })
       .remove();
```

**EDIT**
This section rules the start position of the line.

```
  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
      if (d.depth == 1){
        return [d.y+boxWidth/2, d.x];//now line will end to the box width for depth 1.
      } else {
        return [d.y+70, d.x];
      }

});
```

**EDIT Again**

To make the link touch the start of the box do

```
  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
      if (d.depth == 1){
        return [d.y-boxWidth/2, d.x];//now line will end to the box width for depth 1.
      } else {
        return [d.y+70, d.x];
      }

});
```

To remove the touching backward increase the distance between node:

```
   nodes.forEach(function (d) {
       d.y = d.depth *450;
   });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JUwbxGpNL1T2FieogKnP?p=preview).

Comment: the end point of the arc is not end at the 2nd depth of each box starting how to do this ?

Comment: var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
     .projection(function (d) {
       if (d.depth == 1){
         return [d.y-70, d.x]; //pont should touch with curve at starting of box
       } else {
         return [d.y+70, d.x];
       }
     
 });

Comment: Edited but the curve bending towards backward but not touching the starting position of the box

Comment: It should be same for the next depth how to do it Cyril thanks a lot could u please help me out

Comment: Edited my answer again ! kindly accept it as answer if it wrks.

Comment: Cyril the path line are transparent can we make it not able to see on rectangle box

Comment: huh! are you going to make me do teh whole project!

Comment: If you have a question write the full clear question in the top not go about changing the scope of the question 10 times in the comment!

Comment: children nodes are not closing to its parent node how to close children node to its respective parent node